# Print out a schedule

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

im trying to learn php, html, ajax, and javascript better just to get better at programming. however, I'm stuck on trying to print out the day of the week and the day. I figured i can use date_time and print out the day and week from mysql and then print it to the screen but i am having trouble. So far ive looked up certain functions like

```
week()
```

or

```
date(curdate() - interval weekday(curdate()) day)
```

from other threads but i still cant start the week from Sunday, then print out that day and the rest of the week from it automatically. can anyone help or at least type the functions that i would need to do this? if it helps, the goal is to have it print out like:

```
Sunday 23|monday 24|tuesday 25| ETC
```

EDIT:
I do want to make it clear that im not looking for a design or anything. im mostly trying to to enter a day, like sunday of a certain week, and then print out that entire week

Answer (score 0):

I think your question will be down voted a lot but I would suggest reading through:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634550.aspx

You can add a parameter of 1 to the weekday() function to start your week at Sunday.

Hope that helps some.

Comment: It seems that there are multiple similar questions, I've been seeing lots of downvotes on duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to take a look at [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object.

You should also create a function like this:

```
function printWeek($date) {
    // Start from the given date
    $currentDay = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $date);   
    $currentWeekDay = $currentDay->format("w");

    // Get the first week day
    $day = $currentDay->sub(new DateInterval("P{$currentWeekDay}D"));
    $weekDays = [];

    // Calculate all week days and store it
    do {
        $weekDays[] = $day->format("l d");      
        $day->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
    } while($day->format("w") != 0);

    // Print all weekdays
    echo implode($weekDays, " | ");
}
```

The output will be like:

```
printWeek("2017-07-22");

// Sunday 16 | Monday 17 | Tuesday 18 | Wednesday 19 | Thursday 20 | Friday 21 | Saturday 22
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better ways to do this, but here is my code:

```
$cur_month = date ( 'm' );
$cur_year = date ( 'Y' );
$days_month = cal_days_in_month ( CAL_GREGORIAN, $cur_month, $cur_year ); // Calculate the number of days in the month

// Get month name from number
$cur_dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat ( '!m', $cur_month );
$cur_month_name = $cur_dateObj->format ( 'F' );

$day_count = 1;
while ( $day_count <= $days_month )
{
    $day_count = sprintf ( '%02d', $day_count );
    $full_date = "" . $cur_year . "-" . $cur_month . "-" . $day_count . "";
    $dayname = date ( 'D', strtotime ( $full_date ) );
    echo $dayname . " " . $day_count . "|";
    $day_count++;
}
```

I am using a slightly modified version of this to create a schedule table.

[image]

If you want more info, take a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php